# VBA Reference Cell not change when new row add or delete

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()    
If Range("K59").value = 0 Then    
Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True    
Else    
   Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False    
End If    
End Sub
```

"Sir, I have the following code where Cell K59 has a Sum value of K3 to K50. It is is zero then colum hide and unhide column if K59 has some value. But when I Add or Delete Row in my excel then my Total will come in K60 or K58 but in VBA it is statis as K59 only. How this reference "K59" automatically change when a row delete or add in excel"

Comment: Make K59 a named range and then reference that in the VBA code. That is one way to solve it.

Comment: I completely concur with @Alex P. It is the best ethical solution.

Comment: Thanks sir, Now my problem Solved, thanks u once again

Comment: Sir by naming cell solved above problem by How can the same method apply on Colum K if new colum inserted. Because naming Entire column is not possible or may be possible. How to make Entire Column Dynamic in this above case please

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to find the last non-blank cell in column K:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: This assumes the total in K59 is the last cell in the column. If that holds then agree this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code to dynamically reference the cell

```js
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
If Range("K65000").End(xlUp).Value = 0 Then
Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```